# - MySQL - Delete tables (blogs and plugins) from wordpress MU

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mu

I manage a new WPMU installation clone but I want clear a part of subdomains.
When I delete a suddomain from Wordpress MU (clone), all tables get dropped but all the tables where a plugin need write is still here.

Then there is SQL command like (to delete all tables in one shot):

```
DELETE from 'wp_ID' to 'wp_ID'
```

but delete all primary table and all sub-table like `wp_ID_plugin`
Because I have some residual table after maybe 10 or 15 tables with ID from plugins.

I ask this because I have a Wordpress MU with over 600 website and I split it into two wordpress MU.

Edit /

I choose another way to try to clean database. I found a sample code
[Delete Extra Plugin Tables When a Site Is Deleted in WordPress Multisite](https://gist.github.com/cgrymala/488e77ebc60a0df8198f)
And adapt array for my specific tables

```
$plugin_tables = array( 'statistics_useronline', 'statistics_visit', 'statistics_visitor', 'csp3_subscribers', 'ewwwio_images', 'mappress_maps', 'mappress_posts', 'revslider_css', 'revslider_layer_animations', 'revslider_navigations', 'revslider_sliders', 'revslider_slides', 'revslider_static_slides', 'sendpress_autoresponders', 'sendpress_list_subscribers', 'sendpress_queue', 'sendpress_subscribers', 'sendpress_subscribers_meta', 'sendpress_subscribers_status', 'sendpress_subscribers_tracker', 'sendpress_subscribers_url', 'sendpress_url', 'statistics_exclusions', 'statistics_historical', 'statistics_pages', 'statistics_search', 'statistics_useronline', 'statistics_visit', 'statistics_visitor', 'yoast_seo_links', 'yoast_seo_meta' );
```

I will manage this next week, seems work over "test tables"